# Resize image and it's bounding box in x,y,w,h format

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image of width 1980 and height 1080 having x =759 ,y = 786, w = 369,h = 100. I want to convert this image into width = 640 and height = 480. How can I convert bounding box according to new image format?

I was trying something similar to

```
newX = (newW/W) * x
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know the actual (W,H) and new image format (newW,newH) then

```py
newX = (newW/W) * x
```

and do the same for other value...

Edit:

```py
newY = (newH/H) * y
```

And the same for other value.

Comment: Could you please enlighten me more about newY, new bounding box width and new bounding box height?

Comment: I don't have edit acces but newY should be newY = (newH/H)*y

Comment: You're right I wrote too fast

Comment: How about finding new boundingboxwidth,newboudingboxheight